# Display logfile live time in PlainTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In Python I am using tailhead to 'tail' a file. I want to show the new lines of this file in a PyQt PlainTextEdit box - which I've called display.

I've tried a number of different 'solutions' that I've found online and am coming up short.

Below is what I've tried last.

```
for line in tailhead.follow_path('logfile.log'):
if line is not None:
        self.display.appendPlainText(str(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

No blocking functions should ever be used in the main Qt thread, and since `follow_path` is blocking, it will freeze the whole interface.

The solution is to use a QThread that emits a signal whenever a new line is detected:

```
class Watcher(QtCore.QThread):
    newLine = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        for line in tailhead.follow_path(self.path):
            if line is not None:
                # new line found, emit a signal with its contents
                self.newLine.emit(line)
            else:
                # no new lines, let's sleep a bit to avoid unnecessary requests
                self.msleep(10)

class TailWatch(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, path='logfile.log'):
        super().__init__()
        logger = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(logger)

        # read the contents of the files
        try:
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                logger.appendPlainText(f.read().rstrip('\n'))
        except:
            # no file found or no read access
            pass

        self.watcher = Watcher(path)
        self.watcher.newLine.connect(logger.appendPlainText)
        self.watcher.start()
```